# How can I install Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 16.04 without losing any file

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

My HP 255 G4 came with MS-DOS and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it. Is there any way i can install windows 10 after installing ubuntu without losing any of my files? I have not created any partitions by the way.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I've seen different articles but none mentioned anything about data loss.

Output of sudo parted -l

```
Model: ATA ST500LT012-1DG14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                  
Flags
1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  
boot, esp
2      538MB   492GB  492GB   ext4
3      492GB   500GB  8003MB  linux-swap(v1)


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  
/dev/sdb
has been opened read-only.
Model: Generic- SD/MMC/MS PRO (scsi)                                      

Disk /dev/sdb: 7745MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  7745MB  7744MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Comment: You never will  get assurance on not losing data. At all times you need good backups particularly if changing system around. Is this UEFI or BIOS? Windows can only be installed to a primary NTFS partition with boot flag if BIOS/MBR. And drive must be gpt if UEFI. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: My backup is set to every 2 weeks and my laptop is UEFI. I've posted the output of sudo parted -l   @oldfred

Comment: I would suggest using gparted to shrink sda2 to make unallocated space for Windows. Window wants a variety of partitions and just letting it create those it need should be ok. Just be sure to boot Windows in UEFI mode as that is then how it installs. It should just create these: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions